# MySql query select complex max()

Tags: mysql, database, max, statements

I have these records

[image]

What I want is to find max value in balance and retrieve it with the associated name (I have foreign keys userid==balanceID), for example in this case it would be "name2 | 2000".
Is here any Mysql'ist who could tell me how to achieve this?

I tried something similar to

```
SELECT MAX(b.balance), i.name 
from balance b, usr i 
WHERE i.userid=b.balanceID;
```

BUT it doesnt assign correct name to MAX value from balance. Any help?;]

Comment: There seem to be no common field (for a join) between your tables, ie I can't see a way of connecting a balance to a user. I think you need to clarify your design.

Comment: He already said, userid == balanceID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `GROUP BY` clause in your query.

```
SELECT   MAX(b.balance) as Maximum_Balance, i.name 
FROM     balance b INNER JOIN usr i 
            ON i.userid=b.balanceID
GROUP BY i.name;
```

or maybe you only want to find the person with the highrd `balance` right?

```
SELECT  b.balance  as Maximum_Balance, i.name 
FROM     balance b INNER JOIN usr i 
            ON i.userid=b.balanceID
WHERE   b.balance = (SELECT MAX(balance) FROM balance)
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/52007/1)

Comment: Right, thank you very much, this was what I was searching for :)))

Comment: humm, I am newbie in this site, how can I do so?:D

Comment: @Omegawow click the `big check mark` at the left side of the answer :)